# Describe all continuous functions on lower limit topology

Tags: general-topology

Describe all continuous functions $f: (\mathbb{R}, \tau_\rightarrow) \rightarrow  (\mathbb{R}, |\cdot|)$, where $(\mathbb{R}, \tau_\rightarrow)$ is lower limit topology.

We know that the bases of this topologies are $([a,b): a<b, a,b \in \mathbb{R})$ and $((a,b): a<b, a,b \in \mathbb{R})$.

To be honest, I don't know what and how I have to describe these functions, because I've never done such an exercise. I was thinking about continuity of the set's left side (because $\tau_\rightarrow$ is clopen), but I doubt that may help me in this case...

I will be grateful for any help and hints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key idea is that for all $x$ the family $\mathcal N_x^\to=\{[x,y)\,:\, y>x\}$ is a fundamental system of neighbourhoods for $x$ in the topology $\tau_\to$. Therefore, by using the definition of continuity at all points, the continuous functions $(\Bbb R,\tau_\to)\to(\Bbb R,\lvert\cdot\rvert)$ are exactly the functions such that $f(x)=\lim_{t\to x^+}f(t)$ for all $x$, id est, what we mundanely call right continuous functions.

Comment: thank you for your answer!